# Concatenating a single column into a single row

Tags: sql-server-2012

I have a query

```
select 
     [I].[name_Text] as [Name] 
        from 
      [dbo].[payments$] [G]
    inner join
        [dbo].[payment$] [H]
    on 
        [H].payments_Id = [G].payments_Id
    inner join
        [dbo].[Payment] [I]
    on 
        [I].[payment_Id] = [H].payment_Id
    WHERE 
        [G].restaurant_Id = 0 and [I].[lang] = 'en'
```

and i got output as

```
Name
-----------------
American Express
EuroCard / MasterCard
VISA
VISA Electron
```

i need an output like     American Express, EuroCard / MasterCard, VISA, VISA Electron

I try this query

```
DECLARE @Names VARCHAR(Max)  
SELECT @Names = COALESCE([A].[Name] + ' ','') 
        FROM  
            (select [I].[name_Text] as [Name] from [dbo].[payments$] [G]
        inner join
            [dbo].[payment$] [H]
        on 
            [H].payments_Id = [G].payments_Id
        inner join
            [dbo].[Payment] [I]
        on 
            [I].[payment_Id] = [H].payment_Id
        WHERE 
            [G].restaurant_Id = 0 and [I].[lang] = 'en') A
SELECT @Names as [name]
```

but i got out put as

```
name
----------
VISA Electron
```

any other way to do this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That way of group concatenating is actually unsupported and its behaviour can be undeterministic. Anyway, you need to use:

```
DECLARE @Names VARCHAR(Max) = ''
SELECT @Names = @Names + COALESCE([A].[Name] + ' ','') 
        FROM  
            (select [I].[name_Text] as [Name] from [dbo].[payments$] [G]
        inner join
            [dbo].[payment$] [H]
        on 
            [H].payments_Id = [G].payments_Id
        inner join
            [dbo].[Payment] [I]
        on 
            [I].[payment_Id] = [H].payment_Id
        WHERE 
            [G].restaurant_Id = 0 and [I].[lang] = 'en') A
SELECT @Names as [name]
```